# How to display online users' names on a chat using Socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I've searched on Google a lot, but I cannot find any answers for my specific situation. I just want to display the names of the users who are online in my chat room. My code is divided into two pages:

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
//app setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8080, function(){
console.log('ascoltando la richiesta alla porta 8080');
});
//static 
app.use(express.static('public'));
//socket setup
var io = socket(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('fatta la connessione socket', socket.id);
socket.on('chat', function(data) {
  io.emit('chat', data); 
});
socket.on('typing', function(data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
});
});
```

chat.js (which is the file linked to the html page):

```
//connessione
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080'); // è una variabile socket diversa da quella in             index.js
//query
var message= document.getElementById('message'); 
var handle = document.getElementById('handle');
var button = document.getElementById('send');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');
//scrollbar sempre in basso
function updateScroll(){
var element = document.getElementById("output");
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
}
//emit eventi
button.addEventListener('click',function() {
socket.emit('chat', {
   message: message.value,
   handle: handle.value
}); 
});
message.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
socket.emit('typing', handle.value);
});
//listen eventi
socket.on('chat', function(data){
if (data.message !== "" & data.handle !== "") {
    if (handle.value === data.handle) {
        feedback.innerHTML= "" ;
        output.innerHTML +='<p id=inviato>' +'<span id="utente">'+'Tu' +'</span> <br> ' + data.message +'</p> <br>';
        updateScroll();
        document.getElementById('message').value='';
    } else {
        feedback.innerHTML= "" ;
        output.innerHTML +='<p id=ricevuto>' +'<span id="utente">'+data.handle +'</span> <br> '   + data.message +'</p> <br>';
        updateScroll();
        document.getElementById('message').value='';
    }
} 
});
socket.on('typing', function(data) {
feedback.innerHTML = '<p>'+ data + ' sta scrivendo...' + io.engine.clientsCount;
});
```

Edit: I add the html code, so you can understand the elements I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>MEETY - Torino</title>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="icona.ico">

</head>
<body id="index-body">


        <div id="output"></div>

        <script src="/chat.js"></script>
        <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Cosa vorresti fare..." maxlength="100"  required>
        <button id="send" ><i class="fa fa-send-o"></i></button>




<aside>
    <input id="handle" type="text" placeholder="Il tuo nome" maxlength="18" required>
    <p>Sei a Torino <br> <br> Vai a <a href="milano.html">Milano</a> </p>
    <p id="home"><a href="home.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></p>  
    <div id="feedback"><div id="segnaposto"></div></div> 
    <div id="numero"></div>
</aside>
<script src="/chat.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well what are you seeing? Also, there is nothing related to a username, so how are you supposed to display it?

Comment: The username is “handle”

Comment: I updated my question adding what you aked me.

Comment: I can see that you are doing the chat portion, but where are trying to display the list of all usernames

Comment: I've not already created the div because i don't know how to do it, but, if it helps you, we can consider the div "numero" as the place where the list of usernames will be shown.

Comment: If your question is how to do that, then when a user joins, add their username to a master array called "USERS" that you can emit. Also, in that case, you should remember that Stack Overflow is for a specific problem and not how to complete a general task. Happy coding(and holidays).